# Remove Listener from LocationManger Android GPS

Tags: android, gps

Basically I am trying to stop the GPS from scainning when it can't find a signal, there are some SO on this but not in particular to what I want to do.

I have the following set up in a service.

```
private void grabsensor() {
    this.locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    List<String> enabledProviders = this.locationManager.getProviders(true);

    for (String provider:enabledProviders){
        this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000, 0, this);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to devise my APP so that when it has read the network with an accuracy of less than 30meters, it doesn't scan the GPS, because in my use case the user is inside of a building, this is my way of saving battery.

So I tried to do the following:

```
    // Smart location handling algorithm
    if ((int) location.getAccuracy() < 30) {
        this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
```

Except this will remove all the providers, I just want to remove the GPS one, and then the next time it is called it will check the same if statement if it's false it will add the GPS provider back.

Answer (score 0):

You could create new new instances of Listeners for every provider types. According to documentation there is not any method to check listener is registered.

```
class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    //..
}

private LocationListener locationListenerGPS = new MyLocationListener();

private LocationListener locationListenerOther = new MyLocationListener();

private void grabsensor() {
    this.locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    List<String> enabledProviders = this.locationManager.getProviders(true);

    for (String provider:enabledProviders) {
        if (provider == LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
            this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000, 0, locationListenerGPS);
        else
            this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000, 0, locationListenerOther);
    }
}

private void removeGPSListener() {
    if ((int) location.getAccuracy() < 30) {
        this.locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGPS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I do this though?